# creating new column based on value from other columns panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following  Pandas Dataframe `df`

```
    years    value
0       0   2400.0
1       1   2568.0
2       2   2748.0
3       3   2940.0
4       4   3146.0
5       5   3366.0
6       6   3602.0
7       7   3854.0
8       8   4124.0
9       9   4412.0
10     10   4721.0
11     11   5052.0
```

I would like to create a new column `difference` that is the difference between the column `value`'s current and its previous value e.g

```
    years    value  difference
0       0   2400.0   0
1       1   2568.0   168 # 2568-2400...
2       2   2748.0   180 # 2748-2568...
3       3   2940.0   192 # 2940-2758... and so on..
4       4   3146.0
5       5   3366.0
6       6   3602.0
7       7   3854.0
8       8   4124.0
9       9   4412.0
10     10   4721.0
11     11   5052.0
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `df['diff'] = df['value'].diff()`

Comment: Oh wow, that was really dead simple. Thank you